# MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_MITM_DETECTED?

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-16.04

I've just installed ubuntu 16.04 onto my laptop, but every time I try using a site on my Firefox browser I get a 'mozilla_pkix_error_mitm_detected' error? Reading the details of the error message, it says that a connection couldn't be established because of my default route. I know little about networking, so I'm clueless as to what to do here. Someone help please?

Answer (score 4):

You could enter **about:config** into the firefox address bar (confirm the info message in case it shows up) and search for the preference named **security.enterprise_roots.enabled** double-click it and change its value to **true** and restart firefox.

[image: config firefox]